# Tower of Hanoi using Scala Pure function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iteration, puzzle, towers-of-hanoi

I am new to functional Programming and I'm trying to implement scala Iterative way of implementing tower of Hanoi. I could solve it using the recursion way  but I have difficulty trying to implement it using Iterative method in Scala pure function. The code below is what I have coded so far.

I am using Iterative function since I can simply use it as a stack. So I am trying to avoid using separate functions of implementing it. I have no idea how I can continue from here

```
/**
 * The three pegs of the game. The game starts with all N disks on peg 1 and
 * needs to end with all disks on peg 3.
 */
type Peg = 1 | 2 | 3

case class Move(from: Peg, to: Peg):
  assert(from != to) // Throws and ends the program if violated.
```

```
def towerOfHanoiRecursive(n: Int): Iterator[Move] = {
  var a: Iterator[Move] = Iterator()
  def helper(n: Int, from: Peg, to: Peg, aux: Peg): Iterator[Move] =
    if (n<=0) return a.iterator
    helper(n-1, from, aux, to)
    a = a ++ Iterator(Move(from,to))
    helper(n-1, aux, to , from)

  helper(n, 1, 3, 2)
}
```

```
def towerOfHanoiIterative(n: Int): Iterator[Move] =
  def helper(n: Int, from: Peg, to: Peg, aux: Peg): Iterator[Move] =
    Iterator.iterate((List(Problem(n, from, to, aux)), Iterator.empty[Move])) {
      case (Problem(0, _, _, _) :: _, _) =>
        (List(), Iterator())
      case (Problem(1, x, y, _) :: stackTail, _)  if (stackTail == List() && x == 1 && y ==3 )=> {
        if (stackTail == List() )
          ( stackTail , Iterator(Move(x,y)))
        else if ((stackTail.length %2) == 0)
          (stackTail , Iterator(Move(y,x)))
        else
          (stackTail , Iterator(Move(y,x)))
      }
      case (Problem(1, x, y, z) :: stackTail, _)  =>

          if ((stackTail.length %3) == 0)
            ( stackTail , Iterator(Move(z,x)))
          else if ((stackTail.length %3) == 1)
            ( stackTail , Iterator(Move(z,y)))
          else
            ( stackTail , Iterator(Move(z,y)))
      case (Problem(k, f, t, a)::stackTail, _)  if (n%2) == 0 => {

          if ((stackTail.length %3) ==0)
            (List(Problem(k-1, f, t, a))::: List(Problem(k-1, t,f ,a)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(f,a)))
          else if ((stackTail.length % 3) ==1)
            (List(Problem(k-1, f, a, t))::: List(Problem(k-1, a,f ,t)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(f,a)))
          else
            println("3rd")
            (List(Problem(k-1, a, t, f))::: List(Problem(k-1, a,f ,t)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(a,t)))
      }
      case (Problem(k, f, t, a)::stackTail, _)  if (n %2) == 1 => {
        if ((stackTail.length %3) ==0)
          (List(Problem(k-1, f, t, a))::: List(Problem(k-1, a,f ,t)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(f,t)))
        else if ((stackTail.length % 3) ==1)
          (List(Problem(k-1, f, a, t))::: List(Problem(k-1, f,a ,t)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(f,a)))
        else
          (List(Problem(k-1, a, t, f))::: List(Problem(k-1, f,t ,a)) ::: stackTail   ,Iterator(Move(a,t)))
      }
      
      case (Nil, _) =>
        println("nil")
        (List(),Iterator())
    }.takeWhile { case (p,o) => p.nonEmpty || o.nonEmpty }.flatMap(_._2)
  helper(n, 1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: just use recursion

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use `unfold`?